# Painting in a custom control and the invalidate mechanism

Tags: winforms, custom-controls, invalidation

A custom control I am creating needs to draw many "items" in its client space. A call to Invalidate() would trigger a new paint cycle wherein all items would be redrawn.

Now when there are many items and a lot of navigation happens within the control, things need to be optimized; so I need to trigger a paint cycle where only one or two items are drawn. I store references to these items so that the paint method (OnPaint) knows it's a "quicky".

The difficulty is that when OnPaint is executed, it is hard to know if other Invalidate() calls have been made in the meantime. In that case it should do a "normal", complete paint.

I do make use of the clip rectangle. Of course I could check if the clip rectangle in OnPaint has become the whole of the client rectangle, a sign that Invalidate() was called, but this is not 100% safe. I thought of other similar solutions but they seem hacky.

What is the way this problem is usually, or best, solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution here would be to employ a double buffering approach with the BufferedGraphics class. This way you won't have so much tricky stuff going on in your OnPaint and you'll be able to paint whenever, whatever.

[MSDN: Double Buffered Graphics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b367a457.aspx) (under "Manually Managing Buffered Graphics")

Here's a useful example:
[Custom Drawing Controls in C# – Manual Double Buffering](http://inchoatethoughts.com/custom-drawing-controls-in-c-manual-double-buffering)